# Issues that could happen if importing site-packages from python2.6 to be used with python2.7?

Tags: python, import

I finally managed to install numpy, but it seems to only work in python2.6 . I don't know how to install it in the 2.7 folder (been trying for hours, but I'm just a beginner developer in my first months). Anyway, if I use Python 2.7 and append the absolute path to sys.path, could there be problems?

Any suggestions?

Thank you.

Comment: Installing `numpy` in default configuration should be easy. what is your OS?

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian It's CentOS 6.2, 64 bit. I'll try some more and if nothing seems to work, I'll ask our IT guy to help me out. The beginnings are always hard =/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It could *partially* work but this is a bad idea. **Just don't do it.** Even if it seems to work, it may not. And if it really does, then it will fail randomly in the future.

These are the potential problems that come into my mind:

1. Extensions (those written in C, C++ etc.) are specific to a particular Python version; and numpy has a few extensions, AFAICS. It will work only if you don't use any of them (i.e. use pure Python modules);
2. Python compiles modules into bytecode. The bytecode is specific to a particular Python version. If you use modules from python2.6 directory in python2.7, the compiled files will collide. I doubt this will cause major problems except for the fact that they will be recompiled every time Python version is switched;
3. Python code can be version-specific. It's unlikely for minor versions (but for example Python 2/3 could have serious differences) but still can happen. In other words, the modules installed for Python2.6 can be actually a bit different than those for Python2.7;
4. If you change the loading order, Python2.7 may start loading some standard modules from Python2.6. it could work, it could cause random breakages;
5. It will make all modules installed for Python2.6 visible. It can cause a few random switches somewhere with unpredictable result. I doubt there's something specific for that version but some modules may actually decide to use some kind of deprecated interface finding it visible.

There could be more. You may actually try but be prepared that you may waste a lot of time trying to find out why something does not work as expected later.

And unless I'm missing something, I think installing numpy for Python2.7 involves mostly running the setup *using* Python 2.7; like:

```
python2.7 setup.py clean
python2.7 setup.py build
python2.7 setup.py install
```

Depending on your particular install/system, it may be preferable to use the package manager, binary bundle or a tool like `pip` instead. If you'd like more details on how to enforce Python2.7 with those, you'd have to tell us which one is of your choice.

Comment: Could you provide a short summary at the top, something like: "don't do it. it wouldn't work anyway". btw, `python setup.py` shouldn't be needed in most cases. The simplest way is to [install binaries](http://sourceforge.net/projects/numpy/files/NumPy/1.6.2/) for your OS or use a package manager (apt-get, yum, etc). Even if you decide to install from sources (that requires a working compiler tool-chain, development libraries) `pip install numpy` might be preferable.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: I agree. Added.

Comment: @MichałGórny very informative, thank you. I will try to install it for Python 2.7 then. I have tried with rpm, yum and source files, but I just don't know what I'm doing wrong (http://superuser.com/questions/465602/how-to-install-numpy-on-centos-6-2-64-bit). I am planning on just getting the IT guy to help me out in the end, because I think I'm making this more difficult than it actually should be.